# 3D Collision detection and response

Tags: algorithm, lua, 3d, collision-detection

I recently found a great [white paper](http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf) on 3D collisions in video games and wanted to implement the algorithm but I've been running into some issues that I cannot seem to resolve on my own. The algorithm uses a spheroid object for the player/entities, and squishes the world so that the collision algorithm can be simplified as sphere-triangle, then unsquished. This sounds great, but my collisions seem to be sporadic and I cannot see where the issues lie. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zbki6lxsz6fjyj/ld35_stripped.love?dl=1) is a full working example of my code (requires the [LOVE](http://love2d.org) game framework). Normally I'd post some code snippets here, but frankly there is too much relevant code for it to be helpful. If you do not or cannot run the game with LOVE, the .love file can be opened with any archive manager (it is just a zip file). The relevant files are:

- /libs/cpml/modules/collision.lua (the full collision algorithm)
- /libs/cpml/modules/intersect.lua (various intersection algorithms, including sphere-triangle)
- /libs/cpml/modules/mesh.lua (several mesh helper functions)
- /resources/collision.cpp (the original code from the white paper)

I am also open to other algorithms if there is something more efficient or easier than this one that someone could recommend. I've implemented several collision algorithms over the past year during game jams and they were all flawed in one way or another. I really want to get a solid collision system working so I can focus my energy on other things such as game mechanics.

Edit: Here is a video of the collisions in actions (and failing). You will see that the player object often falls through the world, the red collision points are in weird places, etc.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BX4Hdh-bQ5U

Comment: This question is too broad in its current form.  It's not even clear what you mean by "collisions seem to be sporadic."  You're going to have to have to do some debugging to narrow it down then you'll be in a position to ask a more specific question.

Comment: When approaching this problem, i usually find it useful to have collision detection to be a by-product of other optimization techniques used elsewhere in your pipeline. For example if you do frustum culling or occlusion culling or evaluate environment maps for reflections and other lighting effects, you probably already have in place some sort of grid subdivision or proximity lattice of your scene. Chances are you can reuse them as a basis for your collision solver. Probably not the fastest, but surely the easiest as you only have a single structure to optimize many aspects of your game.

Comment: @Adrian It's difficult for me to really pinpoint the problem, which is why I linked to a demo application and full source code. What I mean by sporadic is that the player object collides where it should at some points, collides where it shouldn't at others, and doesn't collide when it should in even more. Maybe I'll take a quick video to show you what I mean?

Comment: @user2464424 Using an octree or the sorts is planned, but for now I am just trying to get the collisions themselves working, not optimised.

Comment: I've added a video.